# What is Localizing SQL Repository Definitions in ATG?

Tags: sql, atg

I read the documents but i don't clearly understand what is explained in this link.
Can somebody explain in detail what it is and What the author tries to explain in that little explanation?

here is the link:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/RepositoryGuide/html/s0901localizingsqlrepositorydefinitio01.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resource bundle is a Java .properties file that contains locale-specific data (Resource bundles contain locale-specific objects.)

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_resource_bundle
- http://docs.oracle.com/javas/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html

In short, you can create a file with translation phrases that will be show when someone uses   the repository when someone uses the Control Center’s Repository Editors.

Answer (score 1):

When a user uses the BCC it picks up the language locale from their RequestLocale. This will then, using the standard [Java Resource Bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_resource_bundle) functionality, allow you to customise the labels next to each one of the elements inside the BCC.

As an example the following definition:

```
        <table name="XXX_MEDIA_CATEGORY" type="auxiliary" id-column-name="MEDIA_ID">
            <property name="buttonText" data-type="string" column-name="BUTTON_TEXT" display-name-resource="buttonText" category-resource="categoryBasics" default="GO BUTTON">
                <attribute name="propertySortPriority" value="8" />
                <attribute name="resourceBundle" value="atg.projects.store.StoreCatalogTemplateResources" />
            </property>
        </table>
```

If you have a StoreCatalogTemplateResources.properties file with the following property:

```
buttonText=Media Category Button
```

It will show up in the BCC editor for the Media Category Item as `Media Category Button`. 
The localisation of the `SQLRepository` items only apply to the BCC editor and does not translate any of the value properties within the repository. To do this you will need to implement some sort of translation solution yourself (ATG 9.x does not come with a data localisation strategy out-of-the-box) though there were some available to purchase from 3rd party vendors. ATG 10.x has now implemented a working version localising repository data.